# Is the story "Conquistadors using plans of Constantinople in the new world" factual?

Tags: roman-empire, byzantine-empire, new-world

As someone from Istanbul, I have always heard stories and legends about the olden Roman city, when it was Constantinople. I am curious about the one I really like, whether it has any truth in it, or is it a just a legend? It goes like this;

"Since Constantinople was build in later years as the new Eastern capital, Romans gave all their best efforts in building and designing the perfect city. The Queen of Cities was so perfect that even during their conquests in the new world Spanish conquistadors carried the detailed plans of it, so that they can use this perfection as the layouts for the cities they plan to found."

This story is especially used as a sad comparison with modern Istanbul's terrible city planning, saying Turks ruined the perfection. Is there any historical evidence for this story?

Comment: Seems like perfection is in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: If you're old enough to have been born in "Constantinople", we should be asking you history questions, not you us.

Comment: @Semaphore I think it must be possible by some technical analysis to get a quantitative  value for the excellence of any given city. The word perfection was just a metaphor for the excellence of the city design.

Comment: @T.E.D. It was officially renamed as Istanbul after the founding of the Turkish Republic, up until then `Konstantiniyye` was often used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Istanbul#Kostantiniyye

Comment: @bureaquete That is not possibly unless **you** define "excellence of the city design" in objectively evaluable terms first.

Comment: @T.E.D. I've edited the question title to make it more objective, can we reopen the question?

Comment: In 15th century, no 'new world', no city planning there by conquistadores; "Turks ruined" is distracting; any src for legend (looks like a quote?); what has your own prior research found (since 2016?)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС updated the question, I think I'd put 15th century randomly, I meant during the conquests and creation of new cities in new world, whenever that was. Essentially it was something like a hearsay, couldn't find no evidence for it.

Comment: Perhaps it may help to clarify what kind of city design we talk about here: eg what features would count (straight streets or 'organic curves'/ integrated quarters or separated ones/central *planning* vs 'private initiative'; maybe deduced in reverse from modern disparaging legend?); or: can you provide a map of pre-1453 Constantinople or a similar one from the Americas?

Comment: @LаngLаngС as I said it was just a urban legend, I don't think there is any more details to it than what I've already said in the question...

Comment: I would back off a bit, and first ask whether the "conquistadores" had any plans to found cities, rather than loot & occupy the fairly extensive ones (Tenochtitlan, Cuzco, &c) that existed there, or which, like El Dorado, they believed to exist.  Certainly they don't seem to have built actual cities until much later.

Comment: The Spanish created many regular square street grids in their new american cities, which implies not just doing the planning before hand, but following it for some years. In contrast, in the Portuguese colonial city plans were much more messy. May is this what your source meant? In defence of the portuguese, their population, specially native pops, were much smaller, so long term plans would make much less sense.

Comment: @jamesqf Spain created a university in Peru in 1551 while Brazil only would have one in the XX c. After the initial looting, the spanish got whole countries with large pops to admin, while the Portuguese only got smaller tribes. The spanish needed cities and administrative clerks much more than other colonizers.

Comment: About XVI colonial city planning, with summary and map pictures. https://www.patriciasendin.com/2014/06/the-spanish-colonial-town-planning.html  somebody could read the original sources and check if there is mention of constantinople.

Comment: The question was closed as opinion based; do they revisions make it more objective?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace if you check the original title, that was the issue, I actually wanted to confirm the validity of the story, not talk about the perfection of the Roman city building.

Comment: Ahh - makes more sense; but that transforms my question to [If you doubt the existing narrative....](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401)  Historical sources & methods rely on sources; in the absence of a source or preliminary research, I wonder whether historical methods can be of any help in answering this question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Romans it appears to have been 4th century historian  Sozomen describes it as a "New Rome" equal in power and influence ,and describes Constantine's success-"He created another senate which he endowed with the same honours and privileges as that of Rome,and he strove to render the city of his name equal in every way to Rome in Italy;nor were his wishes in vain,for by the favor of God ,it became the most populous and wealthy of cities".Source "The mammoth book of how it happened in Ancient Rome"

Comment: My question was to get information about the story of conquistadors using the plans of the city, and whether this story has any truth in it.

Comment: @bureaquete - You should probably consider editing your question to make that more clear. I'd pay particular attention to changing the title. Some users (and I'm often one of them) have a bad habit of answering the title without bothering to read the entire text of the question.

Comment: @bureaquete - Yes it is. Just giving some advice to a question writer here though, not justifying it.